# JavaCV Stitching in Android not working

Tags: android, javacv, image-stitching

I´m developing an Android app where I would like to stitch some images. I´m working with Eclipse and an older version of JavaCV, googlecode (newer version is not working). Now my problem:
I´m trying to stitch two IplImages, but I only get a black picture as a result. I load the two images into a MatVector and call the stitcher (the vector allImages contains frames from a video). 
Here is my code:

```
IplImage testImage = allImages.getIplImage(0);
IplImage testImage2 = allImages.getIplImage(1);
Stitcher s = Stitcher.createDefault(false);

MatVector testVec = new MatVector(2);
testVec.put(0, testImage);
testVec.put(1, testImage2);
IplImage resultI = IplImage.create(testImage.width(), testImage.height(), testImage.depth(), 3);
int status = s.stitch(testVec,resultI);
//check the status of the stitcher
if( status == s.OK )
 {
     Bitmap testImageBitmap = IplImageToBitmap(resultI);
     savePicture(testImageBitmap, 3, "ready");
 }
```

The status of the stitcher is always 1, but s.OK is 0. Can someone give me a hint why the two images are not stitched?

Thanks!

Comment: if you have the source code, you could add logs into the library code. Being that you're using an old version of javaCV its possible its not compatible with android.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I only have the jars and the so-files.. Yeah maybe that´s the problem, but the newer version of javacv is not working in my project, which is unfortunately an eclipse problem. Do you know another tool which I could use for stitching in android?